# Turn the direction of the PointLight

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using PointLight in my ThreeJs project. I need to make it point to the oriented direction in the image below, but I can't change it. below the code

```
const light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.01, 40 );
light.position.set( 0, 0, 30 ); 
//light.rotateY(270); did not work
light.castShadow = true; 
scene.add( light );
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jc6K.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PointLight` doesn't really have a rotation. It acts as a source of light emanating from a single point, and it shines equally in all directions. Think of it as a star, no matter which way it rotates, it still shines in all directions.

If you need a light that does respond to rotation, you might want to consider a `SpotLight` or a `DirectionalLight`. See the image below for a visual representation:

[image]

Comment: I understood. 
How can I change the aperture to light the whole scene?

Comment: @Brandalize There are several ways to change the brightness. You have `decay, distance, intensity...` I recommend you read through [the documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/PointLight) to read about each property.

Comment: I checked the documentation, but I didn't find anything that allowed me to change the angle

Comment: @Brandalize That's because a point light doesn't have angle. I feel like we're talking in circles here, I just explained why it doesn't have an angle.